# Trying to install wordpress on xampp but can't resolve 404 error

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache, xampp, localhost

I'm installing WordPress on XAMPP for the first time. I downloaded the latest version of WordPress and extracted the standard 'wordpress' file into 'htdocs' as the installation guide directed. However, after trying to reach http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/setup-config.php
I keep receiving a 404 not found error - The requested URL was not found on this server.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you reach http://localhost/wordpress?